# Finding an array of characters in a string

Tags: c

I've written some code that I believe is very close to the answer of the problem, but I can't seem to properly compare two characters. I don't know how to properly cast them.

I know how to do this using arrays, but I want to know how to do it using pointers.

```c
char *FindToken(char *s,char *t)
{
    while (s)
    {
        //char check = *(char*)s; tried this but it doesn't work
        while(t)
        {
            if (strcmp(s,t)){
                //return s;
                printf("%s", s);
            }
            t++;
        }
        s++;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

**This is the original problem:**

> Write a `C function` called that accepts **2** parameters: a `null` terminated character array (string) called **S** in reference to the string to be searched, and a second string parameter called `T`. The `string T` is a `list of characters` (not including the ‘\0’) that are tokens, or characters to be searched for in `S`. Do not modify either `S` or `T`. It will `return` a character pointer to the position of the first character in `T` that is found in `S`, if it is found in `S,` or `NULL` otherwise.

For example:

```c
printf("%s", *FindToken(“are exams over yet?”, “zypqt”)); // will display “yet?”
```

Comment: Do we need the brackets around `t++` in line 12?: `(t++);`?

Comment: Check `strtok` function. I think it going to help you.

Comment: `strcmp` compares the whole strings not characters.

Comment: You probably can't use it, but this assignment is to write a version of the standard [strpbrk()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strpbrk) function, fwiw.

Comment: @MOehm right sorry

Comment: You can do it in linear time O(input-size) as well using precomputed automaton

Answer (score 7):

You were almost close.

With few problems.

1. When you do `(t++)`, ultimately you are making `t` to  point end of its memory and leading UB.
2. `strcmp` is not for comparing `char` as you wanted.

---

```
char *FindToken(char *s,char *t)
{
    while (*s)
    {
        int i = 0;
        //char check = *(char*)s; tried this but it doesn't work
        while(t[i])
        {
            if (*s == t[i])) {
                printf("%s", s);
                return s;
            }
            i++;
        }
        s++;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: @EdHeal Yes even little shorter :). But `I've written some code that I believe is very close to the answer of the problem` OP wanted to know his mistake in the current code only.